# 100% width fixed div has left margin only in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-7

I have this piece of code below, and it works fine in every modern browser and in Internet Explorer for the most part, but not in IE7.

The header is not filling the whole body width and it appears that in IE7 the header div has a left margin. It starts from where the main div is located.

Anybody an idea how I can fix this?

**CSS**

```
div#header {
    z-index: 200;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #232323 0%, #1f1f1f 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #3a3a3a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 13px;
}

div[role=main] {
    position: relative;
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 52px 15px 45px 15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">header content</div>
<div role="main">main content</div>
```

Comment: I think IE7 is pretty outdated now, is our responsability to impulse changes on the way our clients use the Web ... but anyway if you can share your link or a live example to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

to `div#header`

It's always a good idea to specify a top and left, IE seems to like that